# check interval with a condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks for focus every 300ms, and I need this function to skip one time when I press a button witch active another function, and then after that to work normally if I didn't press this button.

```
function checkPageFocus() {

    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    let log = document.getElementById('log');

    if (document.hasFocus()) {
        log.textContent = 'This document has the focus.';
        body.style.background = '#fff';
    } else { 
        alert("lost foucs");
    }

}

inter = setInterval(checkPageFocus, 300);
```

the 2nd function that I call by press a button is

```
function myFunction(){

    window.parent.Popup.closeLast();

}
```

I need to make the first function to work normally every `300ms` 
but if I called `myfunction` I need it to have an interval of `1000ms` then start to work as normal after that, I tried to pass a variable in the setInterval but it keeps working only every 300ms, both functions are in the same .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic:

```js
var skip = false, count = 0;
function checkPageFocus() {
 count++;
 if(!skip){
  console.log(count);

  if (document.hasFocus()) {
    // do what you want
  } else { 
     alert("lost foucs");
  }
 } else {
  skip = false;
 }
}
inter = setInterval(checkPageFocus, 3000);
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  skip = true;
});
```

```html
<input id=myBtn type=button value=myBtn />
```

Comment: I put both functions in the same js file, and i put  myFunction under var skip = false; but I still get the alert("lost foucs");

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your problem?

Comment: I tried to follow your answer, but it seems that checkPageFocus() can read skip as always false, even i press the button to active the other function it do other actions in the function like closing the popup but skip is still false

Comment: @MohamedElsayed I've edited the logic with a working snippet.

Comment: it didn't work with me, I have a separate PHP file after I placed the js part in the .js file. it seems that it can not get the element id, I also src the .js file in the PHP file, but the variable is not changing

Comment: As I can't see your full code, I can't say what's the actual problem. But you can solve it by having a flag "skip"(as in my above logic) which can be accessed from both the functions.

Comment: I solved it, I need to use parent. for declaring instead of var becuae I have an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` for the next run

```
let interval = 1000;

function checkPageFocus() {

  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let log = document.getElementById('log');

  if (document.hasFocus()) {
    log.textContent = 'This document has the focus.';
     body.style.background = '#fff';
  } else { 
      alert("lost foucs");
  }

  setTimeout(checkPageFocus, interval);
}
```

Now you can set `interval = 300` to something else from any other function. This is the simplest way and could use improvements such as not allowing any other function to change that value, but it should solve your problem

Comment: but in this way, the function is not gonna work automatically and check for focus, because I add the setTimeout inside it

Comment: @MohamedElsayed Not sure what you mean, you call the function initially to get it started.